# Pl/SQL Bulk Migration of some columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know that there are many bulk insert script, since I am new at pl/sql I am confused.
I have two tables  TABLEA(id,name,sirname,age)  TABLEB(id,age), I want to migrate all data from TABLEB to TABLEA.

I have found a link http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html in which "FORALL Insert" explains how to do that. But It assumes two table column type is same. But in my case I will copy to some columns on TABLEA.

Since TABLEB have 30Million record, performance is important.
One more thing I would like to say TABLEB is external table, I mean it is created from txt file mapping proper column into table.

So What can be done to modify the following script for my case.

```
CREATE TABLE servers2 AS
SELECT *
FROM servers
WHERE 1=2;

DECLARE
 CURSOR s_cur IS
 SELECT *
 FROM servers;

 TYPE fetch_array IS TABLE OF s_cur%ROWTYPE;
 s_array fetch_array;
BEGIN
  OPEN s_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH s_cur BULK COLLECT INTO s_array LIMIT 1000;

    FORALL i IN 1..s_array.COUNT
    INSERT INTO servers2 VALUES s_array(i);

    EXIT WHEN s_cur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE s_cur;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the fastest way is to use a plain old INSERT with the APPEND hint:

```
 INSERT /*+APPEND*/ INTO table_a(id,age)
  SELECT id, age
  FROM table_b;
```

No need for FORALL / BULK COLLECT etc.

Comment: Definitely the better approach.

Comment: I have two questions, first do I have to tune the limit since I have 30M data, second if table_a is not empty and it has common data with table_b which violates primary key constraints. Is there a way of ignoring the tupples in such cases.

Comment: @mmc18 #1 no (30MB is not much data). #2 is out of the scope of this question (hint: see [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)) !

Comment: If it's a matter of just ignoring new rows where there is a primary key violation, rather than updating the table to the new value, then just use a NOT EXISTS correlated subquery or a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Just to add, if you're repeatedly adding and deleting rows from tablea then inserting into it using APPEND is going to leave some empty or partly empty blocks in the table. You can deal with that by either not using APPEND or by coalescing the table prior to the insert, or by copying the data elsewhere and truncating the table then inserting back both the old data and the new data in one insert.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to change anything for external table. You can probably increase the limit to 100000 since you have 30M data. But it purely depends on your database design and how much traffic you have. But i prefer increasing the limit.

Comment: No, forget about the limit and the PL/SQL cursors entirely. This is a job for SQL.

Comment: 30 million rows is huge data. doing a single insert may take time and result in snapshot too old error. I would prefer PL/SQL block for this.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with all of that. 30 million rows ought to be a trivial single SQL insert, which would be faster and more efficient than a PL/SQL-based approach. A snapshot-too-old error is very unlikely, especially with an external table as the data source and a direct path insert, as there is very little requirement for the query to need to reconstruct blocks from the UNDO data.

Comment: I dint keep external table in mind when i was answering. Thanks for pointing it out.